# rowwiseからのmutate

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

dplyrでrowwiseからのmutateを試みていますが、うまく行かないです。

・以下コードを実行すると、エラーになります。

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(row_max= max(starts_with("X")))
Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
```

・そのため、回避して

```
col %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(row_max= max(X1:X17))
```

とすると、一番大きい値が引っかからないです。
1.90e-3や7.54e-3 のような値が入っているため正確に判断されていないのでしょうか。
（1.90e-3と7.54e-3が同じ行にあるのに1.90e-3がmaxとして選ばれているようです。
1.90e-3<7.54e-3はTrueと出るのですが。）

詳しい方、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::pmap()`を使うのが良いかと思います。

```
# irisデータの"Sepal"から始まる最大値をmutate
iris %>% mutate(max = select(., starts_with('Sepal')) %>% pmap(., ~ max(.)))
```

Comment: starts_withは作動するようになりました。ありがとうございます。
ただ、正しい最大値をとってくることはできていないです。

Comment: 各行の最大値をとってきたいということですよね？`iris`データですと期待通りの結果になります。 `ungroup()`を`mutate`する前に実行してみて下さい。また、`str(df)`で当該列の型を確認してみて下さい。

Comment: str()はnumでした。ungroup()しても結果は変わらずでした。
自分もirisだと正しい結果が帰ってくるのですが…